# Angular HTTP POST method if condition not working

Tags: angular, if-statement, post, methods, conditional-statements

In angular 7, I am getting an error while using Http POST. But when I try to use that error value in if condition, the if condition is not executed, always else part is getting executed.

angular with node js (MEAN)

```
errorParametre: any ;
this.http.post(`${this.uri}/compare`, {obj , err})
        .subscribe(res => {
           this.errorParametre = res['res']['err'].error;
           console.log(this.errorParametre);
           if (this.errorParametre === true) {
            console.log('hello');
            } else {
             console.log('irritating');
            }
           });
          }
```

`console.log(this.errorParametre) => true` but also
not able to go inside if condition .. only `false` getting executed always

Comment: Check with `this.errorParametre == true` (double equals), the return you are getting might be a string

Comment: Is your "err" value `true` or `"true"`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are receiving error value as string so check condition like this

```
this.errorParametre === 'true'
```

Comment: yes , thank u so much .. i was getting error value as string but i was trying to compare it with boolean .. that was the reason..

Answer (score 0):

Please handle error something like this: -

```
this.http.post(`${this.uri}/compare`, {obj , err}).subscribe(
      response => {
          console.log('Successful');
      },
      err => {
          console.error("Error");
          this.errorParametre = true
      }
);
```